# AngularJS issue with templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have started to study Angular just a little time. I am trying to write an example of Custome Directive with TemplateURL. The problem is that in the new custom tag it's not print the result of the template.

To this link you can see the code.
Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="it-IT">

<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello Angular</title>
     <script src="../../angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controApp as ctrl">


        <table border=2>
            <thead>
                <td>AAA</td>
                <td>BBB</td>
                <td>CCC</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <lista-clienti lista="ctrl.elencoClienti"></lista-clienti>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("listaClienti", function() { 
    return { 
      scope: {
        lista : "="
      },
      //template: "<div>missing tpl</div>"
      templateURL: "selectCity.html"
    }; 
  }); 

app.controller('controApp',  function($scope ){

  $scope.elencoClienti  = [ 
        {codiceCliente: "1", ragioneSociale: "Michele Srl", indirizzo_so:"Via delle calende greche" },
        {codiceCliente: "2", ragioneSociale: "Michele Srl", indirizzo_so:"Via delle calende greche" },
    ]; 


});
```

selectCity.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in lista">
    <td>{{c.codiceCliente}}</td>
    <td>{{c.ragioneSociale}}</td>
    <td>{{c.indirizzo_so}}</td>
</tr>
```

what could is the problem?
Thanks

Directory Structure:
05_Custom_Directive
-- Example_02
----index.html
----script.js
----selectCity.html

Comment: Will you paste the directory structure of your application, my hunch is your selectCity.html is not being found by the directive.

Comment: i have add the directory structure ;)

Comment: can you change your selectCity.html to be the below 

`<tr ng-repeat="c in lista">
    <td>{{c.codiceCliente}}</td>
    <td>{{c.ragioneSociale}}</td>
    <td>{{c.indirizzo_so}}</td>
</tr> this i a test`

This will tell us if your template is getting injected  or not.

Comment: nothing, don't work...I also think it is a problem of injection

Comment: did you try a relative url `./selectCity.html`

Comment: nothing, don't work..how i can see, what is the complete url of the templateURL?

Comment: i think you're missing the replace:true in your directive definition too.

Comment: ok and what is the solution? :)

Comment: i have resolved, the problem was the "templateURL". The correct form is "templateUrl" :D

Answer (score 2):

When using ctrlAs syntax use this instead of $scope

```
 this.elencoClienti  = [ 
    {codiceCliente: "1", ragioneSociale: "Michele Srl", indirizzo_so:"Via delle calende greche" },
    {codiceCliente: "2", ragioneSociale: "Michele Srl", indirizzo_so:"Via delle calende greche" },
];
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController, this is the url that suggests to bind your properties to the object instead of the `$scope` when you are using the `as` clause in `ng-controller`.

Comment: ah perfect i don't know this alternative